# How to create a particular profile based on user attribute in Django using signals

Tags: python, django, signals

I have users that are either 'Company' or 'Applicant', each having different attributes. I want to create either a Company Profile or Applicant Profile on sign-up based on the user attribute.

Below is the code I'm using in signals.py and it does not work.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            if sender != User.is_company:
                Applicant.objects.create(user=instance)
            else:
                Company.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_applicant:
        instance.applicant.save()
    else:
        instance.company.save()
```

Comment: It should be `instance.is_company` not `User.is_company`

Comment: And just `if instance.is_company`, not sure why you've tried to use `if sender` there.

Comment: thanks @Ahtisham, that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
if sender != User.is_company:
```

To this:

```
if instance.is_company:
```

User is a class name and instance is its object.

Comment: @WurkGuyana this should be the accepted answer as the other answer does not mention where the error is and how to fix that particular error you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to import signals in your **apps.py**

```
#my_app/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'My App'

    def ready(self):
        import my_app.signals
```

and than in `signals.py`

```
#my_app/signals.py

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_applicant:
        Applicant.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        Company.objects.create(user=instance)
```